# From php I create a HTML form that mult selects items in a table - I want to send the selected items with some bits of information using javascript

Tags: php, html, javascript

Need help sending data from a table in html in a php file sending to a javascript script with parameters from php

```
  ?>
                <form action="http://<?=$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]?>/index.php/search" method="GET" name="multiform">
                <input type="submit" value="Back">
            <?
```

This is one of the items in my table

```
echo "<td class=\"cent\">&nbsp;<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"rids[]\" value=\"{$reportdate}\">&nbsp;</td>";
```

Here I am creating the button to be 'sent' to the javascript function - However I want to be able to send multiple items and I want to be able to send variables from PHP

```
echo"<input type='submit' value='button text' onclick='return view_submit(650,'$reportGarb');' /> ";
```

These are the items that need to be sent through to the next page - they should be filled out in the javascript function

```
echo  "<input type='hidden' name='edit' value='999'>";
echo  "<input type='hidden' name='garcom' value='1'>";
echo  "</form>";
```

This is the function I call from my form submit - the second paramater doesnt get set

```
<script>
function view_submit(subtype,garcom)
{           
    if (has_a_check(document.multiform["rids[]"]) == false)
    {
        alert("You must select some items!");
        return false;
    }
    document.multiform.action='http://<?= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]?>/index.php/search';
    document.multiform.method='GET';
    document.multiform["edit"].value = subtype;
    document.multiform["garcom"].value = garcom;

    return true;
 }
 </script>
```

What I am seeing is a URL like this

```
"..com/search?rids%5B%5D=2013-05-01&edit=999&garcom=1
```

So Is the way I am doing this the best way to do it, and why is the second parameter not being set to my variable that I pass to the js?

If I remove the second parameter the edit becomes 650

Comment: Double quotes are a terrible thing.  Use single quotes and just concatenate the line. '<input value="' . $PHP VALUE . '/>';  I should change this to an answer, it is what's causing your issue.

Comment: Not sure where you are stating that would go...

Comment: Can you post what the the resulting HTML looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the double quotes.  Magic quotes are the worst idea php ever had.  They are phasing them out because they realized this an it only creates coding nightmares.

CHANGE

```
 echo "<input type='submit' value='button text' onclick='return view_submit(650,'$reportGarb');' /> ";
```

TO

```
 echo '<input type="submit" value="button text" onclick="return view_submit(650, "' .  $reportGarb . '");" />';
```

OR BETTER YET

```
 <input type="submit" value="button text" onclick="return view_submit(650, "<?php echo $reportGarb ?>");" />
```

Comment: String interpolation has nothing to do with "magic quotes". And unless you think this will actually solve the problem, it's not an answer.

Comment: His variable is not getting there, its a great place to start.

Comment: Since all these things are equivalent, it's not a likely place to end. Coding style recommendations belong in comments, not answers.